# Wordpress+mysql helm deployment

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes-helm

Learning kubernetes, docker and helm;
I am diving into a Devops programm, and have been asked to deploy a wordpress+mysql with helm at my internship enterprises. Tried to do something but the wordpress is unable to connect to the database and i think the database is not able to write to the mounted nfs volume path; really need help and explanation if possible.. tried everything i saw but did not work.

The error i have from wordpress in web browser is **Error connecting to databases**

Here is my project manifest files, pods status

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
   - port: 3306
     name: wordpress-mysql
     protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: wordpress
      nodePort: 32000
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
  type: NodePort
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: bitnami/mysql
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: root
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-pvc
          mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pvc

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress:5.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
          value: wordpressdb
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: test123
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-pvc
          mountPath: "/var/www/html"
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress-pvc
```

**Pods status**

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/wordpress-fcf86fbd9-q9csh          1/1     Running   0          34h
pod/wordpress-mysql-6dfb484d54-wrlnm   1/1     Running   0          34h


NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1             443/TCP        9d
service/wordpress         NodePort    10.98.97.25           80:32000/TCP   34h
service/wordpress-mysql   ClusterIP   10.97.50.98           3306/TCP       34h


NAME                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/wordpress         1/1     1            1           34h
deployment.apps/wordpress-mysql   1/1     1            1           34h

NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/wordpress-fcf86fbd9          1         1         1       34h
replicaset.apps/wordpress-mysql-6dfb484d54   1         1         1       34h
```

Thank in advance for your help. Really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your **DB** password and **WordPress** connection password that you are adding into for connection both are different, ideally, it should be the same.

`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : root` but `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: test123` try with updating the password for Wordpress so it can connect to **MySQL**.

`WORDPRESS_DB_NAME` you have created this DB into MySQL or just adding name ? directly ? it could be due to Wordpress finding for that db and you have not created it. try following this official tut and check once as it is : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/ it's mostly same only

Comment: thanks for your quick response, appreciate it. I manually created WORDPRESS_DB_NAME once the mysql pod were up. As asked, i updated password to be the same
I followed that tutorial in the beginning too, my error is still the same : 

Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at wordpress-mysql. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Comment: did you tried with creating temp mysql container and connecting it to your setup database is it working ? try setting up debian or busybox container with MySQL cli and try it to connect with your MySQL service you will get idea, either password issue or network issue etc.

Comment: `kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:5.6 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h wordpress-mysql -u root -proot` use this command and update host and password accordingly. if this not work go inside mysql container and check root user have access connect over `%` or just from `localhost`

Comment: Hello @Harsh ; thank you for your great help so far. I am now able to get it working.
The issue was related to kube-system core dns itself pod. had to find another script to run from https://github.com/coredns/deployment.gi , and it did the work
Thank, mind if i add you on my linkedin please??